# "HTTP 406 Not Acceptable" When trying to send PDF converted to base64. C# xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, post, http-post, http-status-code-406

I'm doing a POST method to an end point with a PDF that is converted to base64 but I'm receiving a HTTP 406 CODE. I included in the body the application/pdf for mime type and I included the necessary header to accept my POST request but still I'm receiving the 406 code. Does the json body has any connection on receiving the 406 code or am I having a problems on my header? Please see attached image for the details of the end point and json body.

```
public class MyFile
{
    [JsonProperty("mime")]
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public string Base64Data { get; set; }
}

public class PdfFile
{
    [JsonProperty("file")]
    public MyFile myFile { get; set; }
}

string pdfBase64;
const string pdfFileName = "file.pdf";
    
                    using (var pdfStream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(pdfFileName))
                    {
                        using (var pdfReader = new StreamReader(pdfStream))
                        {
                            var fileContents = await pdfReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                            pdfBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContents));
                        }
                    }
    
                    var file = new MyFile();
                    var pdf = new PdfFile();
                    file.MimeType = "application/pdf";
                    file.Base64Data = "base64-data=" + pdfBase64;
                    pdf.myFile = file;
    
    
                    var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pdf.myFile);
                    string baseUrl = "https://goodmorning-axa-dev.azure-api.net/upload";
    
                    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
                        .Accept
                        .Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    
                    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, baseUrl);
                    requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    requestMessage.Headers.Add("x-axa-api-key", apiKey);
    
                    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
                    string responseAsString = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
                    if (responseAsString != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(responseAsString);
                    }
```

Comment: `file.Base64Data`... Hmmm, doesn't your requirements state that the field with the data must be called `data`? Also, `myFile`? Shouldn't be `file`?

Comment: does `jsonContent` match the json structure required by the service?  406 is an uncommon error code - you should review the API docs to see what might cause it.

Comment: The pdf file should be the body of the request. Why are you using JSON?  Are you attaching multiple objects to the request?

Comment: @Gusman yes. I'm actually using "file". Please see my edits.

Comment: @jdweng one of the requirements is to convert the PDF file to base64 string. So I converted the file to base64 and included the string to the json body.

Comment: Then you have conflict.  The mime type and body have to match.  You could use GZIP which is the same as base64.  So I would get rid of json and instead just specify GZIP.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: `pdf.myFile` is not the same as `pdf.file`, your json body will look like this with your structure: `{ "myFile": { "Base64Data": "(whatever)" } }` also you must serialize `pdf` not `file`. ANd now that I realize even the mime field is wrong, you named it `MimeType` instead of `mime`.

Comment: if you look at his class definitions he has attributes to map the json field names

Comment: the API docs he is following specify the required value for the mime type property, which he is setting correctly

Comment: @Gusman in my class definition, I have mapped the myFile to to [JsonProperty("file")]. and same to the others, I have mapped the correct json field names.

Comment: @Jason when he posted the question the class definitions wheren't there so I could not know it.

Comment: error404, the problem then is that you are serializing `pdf.myFile`, not `pdf`.

Comment: I asked him to check that 2 hours ago - "does jsonContent match the json structure required by the service?"

Comment: @Jason yes. I also tried to use postman to manually create the json body based on the requirements and I still receive 406 code.

Comment: if you can't even get it to work from PostMan I suggest you contact the owner of the service and ask for help